# Link 2 viewmodels in my MVVM app

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm currently managing 2 fragments in my app which I developped using MVVM.

- Fragment A is composed of ViewA (which extends Fragment), ViewModel A (extends ViewModel), and Model A (let say POJO objects even if I'm looking info in Firebase realtime database))
- Fragment B has the same architecture of A

My problem is that Model A contains data I need to read in Fragment B.

Let's take an easy example:

- Model A:

int IdItem;

int nameItem;

- Model B:

int programName;

int linkedItem;

In my Fragment B, I will need to display programName, and linked nameItem (instead of its ID).

How can I manage that ?

Even if I observe data A in fragment B, how to update data coming from A in my adapter B ...

Comment: Why don't you let the host activity supply the data?

Comment: Why not but how would you do that?

Comment: Write public getter functions in the fragments using which the activity could pull and push data